# cryptojs aes 256 encryption and java decryption

Tags: java, aes, cryptojs

I encrypted message with cryptojs aes 256 on the client side. But couldn't decrypt it on the java side. First, I pass the key directly to the server side as hex, then convert it from hex to java bytearray. It didn't work. Then I pass the phrase, salt, iv to the server as hex. Then generate the key. It still didn't work. It always to complain the key length is not right.

Client side:

```
var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
var salt_hex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(salt);

var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(256/32);
var iv_hex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(iv);


var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(secret, salt, { keySize: 256/32, iterations: 10 });
var key_hex=CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(key);

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, { iv: iv });    

var encryptedtxt = secret+":"+salt_hex+":"+iv_hex+":"+encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)+":"+key_hex;
```

Server side:

```
    if (encrypted != null)
    {
        //Get the passphras, salt, IV and msg
        String data[] = encrypted.split(":");
        String passphrase = data[0];
        String salt_hex = data[1];
        String iv_hex = data[2];
        String msg64 = data[3];
        String jskey_hex = data[4];
        byte[] jskey = hexStringToByteArray(jskey_hex);
        byte[] iv = hexStringToByteArray(iv_hex);
        byte[] salt = hexStringToByteArray(salt_hex);
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        byte[] msg = decoder.decodeBuffer(msg64);

        try {
             //theClear = AES.decrypt(encrypted);
            /* Decrypt the message, given derived key and initialization vector. */
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), salt, 10, 256/32);
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
            String plaintext = new String(cipher.doFinal(msg), "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: If "the key length is not right", then your problem might be leading zeros.  Does the `stringify()` method convert `[0x01, 0x02, 0x03]` to `"123"`?  Your decryption code probably assumes `"010203"`.  `"123"` will probably give a two byte array, `[0x12, 0x03]`, which does not match the input and is the wrong length.  That is fatal for a crypto key.

Comment: `256/32 == 8`, while supported key sizes for AES are 16, 24 or 32 bytes. You will have to modify both JS and Java code to use key of at least 16 bytes.

Comment: rossum - the hex stringified key is like 010203. But I do hex decode on the java side to byte array. I wonder how the word array on JS to match with byte array on java?

Comment: Your IV is also sized incorrectly in the CryptoJS. AES uses 128 bit blocks, and the IV should therefore be 128 bits as well.

Comment: Owlstead - You are absolutely right on the IV. Changing that.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. By default JRE 7 doesn't support 256-bit key. I had to download the new jars from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html and overwrite them in the jre/lib/security folder. You will have to do the similar thing for the Websphere 6 or 7. If you don't do it, it prompts "illegal key size". I've also seen "illegal key size x", where x is a number. That means the key size is not right. Below are the code.

Server side:

```
//@Override
public String getClearText() throws IOException {
    // Get the body
    String encrypted = super.getParameter("aes"); //base64

    if (encrypted != null)
    {
        //Get the passphras, salt, IV and msg
        String data[] = encrypted.split(":");
        String passphrase = data[0];
        String salt_hex = data[1];
        String iv_hex = data[2];
        String msg64 = data[3];
        String jskey_hex = data[4];
        byte[] jskey = hexStringToByteArray(jskey_hex);
        byte[] iv = hexStringToByteArray(iv_hex);
        byte[] salt = hexStringToByteArray(salt_hex);
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        byte[] msg = decoder.decodeBuffer(msg64);
        String plaintext = "";
        try {
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(jskey, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
            plaintext = new String(cipher.doFinal(msg), "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("in filter, decrypted: " +plaintext);
    }
    return plaintext;
}
```

Client:

```
$(function() {

$('#test').on('submit', function() {

var plaintext = $('#text').val();
var secret = '0123456789abcdef';

var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
var salt_hex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(salt);

var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
var iv_hex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(iv);


var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(secret, salt, { keySize: 256/32, iterations: 1 });
//var key_hex=CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(key);
var key_hex= key;

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, { iv: iv });    


//decrypt
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      encrypted,
      CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key_hex),
      { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv_hex) });

var text = decrypted.toString( CryptoJS.enc.Utf8 );
//console.log(encrypted);

// ----- base64 encoding ----------
var encryptedtxt =     secret+":"+salt_hex+":"+iv_hex+":"+encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)+":"+key_hex;
console.log('html - ciphere txt : ' +encryptedtxt);

// ---- testing ----
//var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key,{iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv)});
//console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

post ('/E2Efilter/TheServlet', encryptedtxt);
return false;
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're storing your key with all of the other parameters (iv/salt/encrypted data), so why did you encrypt in the first place? An attacker could decrypt the data just as easily.